# create field merging info from other tables and fields

Tags: mysql, merge

i need to create a field in my table in order to put a title to all my properties for sale. I am not a programmer but i studied a little mysql, and I cant find a solution to this.

I need to fill in a field in a mysql table using information from different tables, let me explain.

I have a table named "products" where the locality and category are defined with a number (id), then I have another 2 tables named "localities" and "categories" where a string is assigned to the id number of the "products" table, ex:

in products table i have a product with locality id n. 10 and category id n.17, in localities table the id n.10 has the value "locality 1" and in categories table the id n.17 has the value "houses for sale".

Well, i need to update the products table and set the "title" field using information from the other tables and create a title string for ALL ROWS using the info from the other tables, in order to have titles similar to the following one:

```
"Houses for sale in locality 10"
```

and for example

```
"Apartments for sale in locality 23"
"Land for sale in locality 34"
```

etc.

Please note that the word "in" is not part of any table so I need to insert it in the middle in some way. I hope i have been clear enough, if not please ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using `update` with `join`.  Here is an example:

```
update products p join
       localities l
       on p.localityid = l.locality id join
       categories c
       on p.categoryid = c.categoryid
    set p.title = concat(c.value, ' in locality ', l.value);
```

Comment: thanks my friend, i will try and let you know, thank you a lot.